# NoneType AttributeError with multiple html files

Tags: python, file, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nonetype

I am trying to find the `tr` tag from the `financialStatement` table. Everything works fine until I code the last line `rows = statement.findAll ( 'tr' )`, which gives:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'
```

Here the html file: http://investing.businessweek.com/research/stocks/financials/financials.asp?ticker=TSCO:LN

```
import os
import urllib,re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup 

path = '/Users/projectfile/'
listing = os.listdir(path)

for infile in listing:
    print "current file is: " + infile
    fileIN = open(path+infile, "r")
    line = fileIN.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup ( line )
    statement = soup.find ( 'table' , { 'class' : "financialStatement" })
    rows = statement.findAll ( 'tr' )
```

Comment: The `financialStatement` table is not found, so `statement` is `None`. Interestingly, I *cannot* reproduce that problem with the URL you gave us.

Comment: Did you just not know that `find` can return `None` if nothing is found (meaning you need some error handling, e.g., `if not statement: continue`)? Or did you know that, but not expect `find` to ever fail in this case, so you need help looking at the HTML/`soup.find` call?

Comment: As a side note, it's very misleading to call an entire document's contents `line`.

Comment: Meanwhile, which versions of BeautifulSoup and Python are you using? And are you sure that's the file that it's failing on? Because when I try with BS 3.2.1 or 4.1.3 under Python 2.7.2, or (with minor changes to deal with the charset) with 4.1.3 under 3.3.0, they all successfully find a table with 25 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that `statement` in None.  So probably this line: `soup.find ( 'table' , { 'class' : "financialStatement" })` doesn't find anything and returns None.

You could add an if statement to test if statement has a value:

```
if statement:
   rows = statement.findAll ( 'tr' )
else:
   rows = None
```